# Can I specify a fallback preference for a "should" query?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have two documents in an index, with `locale` values `en` and `pt`,

```
{
  "slug": "my-object",
  "locale": "en",
}

{
  "slug": "my-object",
  "locale": "pt",
}
```

and I run a query where the result *should* be in a locale I don't have, `fr`,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":  [{ "term": { "slug":   "my-object" } }],
      "should":[{ "term": { "locale": "fr" } }]
    }
  },
  "size": 1
}
```

is there a way make it only fall back to a doc with `en` locale, not `pt` or any other?

Basically, I want to say "it *should* be in French, but I will also accept English."

Answer (score 1):

Good news! It looks like recent updates slated for 1.3 release should allow this to work in the general case (more than 1 result, supporting pagination). It isn't in the form of a "should" query, though, it is called the top_hits aggregator:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/6124
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6299

If all you need back is one response or a known small response set applying the logic client side is likely the easiest way to get this going with the least amount of effort. So, you do a should "en", "fr" and ignore the en if the fr comes back.

Another option is modeling the data such that you further denormalize things. Therefore, including all variants of the slug within the same document may simplify things. This could add other complications, so YMMV.